# Computation of generalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we wish to find the eigenvectors of the matrix $$A=\begin{bmatrix}3&2&1\\0&3&2\\0&0&3\end{bmatrix}.$$
The first eigenvector is $x_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$. We get the second (generalized) eigenvector by solving the equation
\begin{equation}(A-3I)x_2=x_1.\tag{*}\end{equation}
Alternatively, we know that $x_2$ belongs to the kernel of $(A-3I)^2$:
\begin{equation}x_2\in\mathcal{N}\left((A-3I)^2\right).\tag{**}\end{equation}
But ($*$) and ($**$) are not equivalent!

In ($*$), the set of solutions is an 1D affine subspace, while ($**$) is a 2D linear subspace. For instance, $x_2=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies ($**$), but not ($*$). In this sense ($*$) is  the correct expression, while using ($**$) can be misleading. However, this does not seem to be reflected/mentioned in most texts treating Jordan forms. Or do I miss something?

Comment: For Jordan decomposition you have to use not just *some* generalized eigenvectors, but generalized eigenvectors that form a *Jordan chain*.

Comment: So you want to say that there are generalized eigenvectors and generalized eigenvectors forming a Jordan chain? Is there any reference that distinguishes between these? Also, what would be the role of generalized eigenvectors not forming a Jordain chain?

Comment: "The first eigenvector is ..." No, *a* first eigenvector is ... – any (nonzero) multiple of an eigenvector is an eigenvector. $x_1=(2,0,0)$ is an eigenvector, and $(A-3I)x_2=x_1$. Alternatively, let $x_2=(0,1/2,0)$ (with $x_1=(1,0,0)$).

Comment: Yes, I see the point. Apparently, there was a reason to give Jordan chains this name. Every chain is attached to a specific original eigenvector, and we cannot mix up generalized eigenvectors from different chains. This seems to support my thesis that the use of notation $x_k\in\mathcal{N}(A-\lambda I)^k$ can be misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the matrix elements and eigenvalues are integers, I like doing the backwards direction, it puts off the fractions until the end. I make a change of basis matrix $P,$  the determinant of $P$ is the only denominator, and can even be displayed as a scalar multiplier when writing $P^{-1},$ so the the elements of all the matrices appear as integers, good for reducing errors.

My new basis of (column) vectors  will be called $(u,v,w)$ and the matrix with those columns $P.$  The final outcome will be $P^{-1} AP = J$ in Jordan form. The size of the largest Jordan block is the degree of the minimal polynomial, which is three. A single block.

As $(A-3I)^2 \neq 0,$  we take $w$ that is not annihilated, I like $w= (0,0,1)^T.$  Next, $v = (A-3I)w = (1,2,0)^T.$  Finally $u = (A-3I)v = (4,0,0)^T.$
This $u$ is the only genuine eigenvector.

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
&& \\
&& \\
&& \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
P= 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
4&1&0 \\
0&2&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

so

$$
P^{-1} = \frac{1}{8}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2&-1&0 \\
0&4&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \; . \; \; 
$$

Then

$$
\frac{1}{8}
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2&-1&0 \\
0&4&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
3&2&1 \\
0&3&2 \\
0&0&3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
4&1&0 \\
0&2&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
3&1&0 \\
0&3&1 \\
0&0&3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: I see, you start off from the last link in the chain and go in the backward direction. But will it work that well if there are several Jordan blocks corresponding to the same eigenvalue?

Comment: @d  you do need to check for linear independence then. Start with the largest block(s) (degree of minimal polynomial). I've never written down a more specific recipe.  It seems to me there was also a need for care with different eigenvalues.  Worth working out and doing examples, let the general criteria come after getting some confidence actually constructing $P$  for $P^{-1} AP = J$

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the standard approach is more "robust", so to say. Anyway, thank you for your help. It's interesting to look at the problem from a different perspective.